# Ayuda con el select en un combobox

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy usando un `select` para guardar datos de una base de datos, pero al momento de seleccionar varios del `select` solo me guarda el último seleccionado de la caja de `combobox` y quiero que por lógica se guarden todos los seleccionados.

Éste es el código que tengo

```
<?php
    require ('../php/conexion2.php');
    $id_clasificacion = $_GET['estado_id'];

    echo 'tipo de emergencia: <select multiple="multiple" size="5" name="tipo"  onChange="getPersonal(this.value) ;"     >';
    $query = "SELECT id_tipo, nombre FROM tipo_emergencia WHERE id_clasificacion= '$id_clasificacion' ORDER BY nombre";

    if($resultado=$mysqli->query($query)){
        while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['nombre']; ?>"><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></option>
    <?php
        }
    }
    echo '</select>';
?>
```

Comment: Hola, puedes colocar el código donde estas capturando los datos del **select multiple** que estas usando.

Comment: Exactamente, ese codigo solo lista los option en un select. El problema es que al pasarle un parametro por GET solo va a mostrar un solo option. O sea, el SELECT siempre va a tener una sola opcion (a menos que lo comparta en varios registros). Me parece que viene por ahi el problema, y si es como lo pienso esta mal planteado el uso de ese codigo.

Comment: La pregunta no está muy clara: ¿tienes problemas al guardar la selección en la base de datos?¿o al leer de la base de datos para generar el combobox? En el primer caso te faltaría el código donde se lee y guarda el parámetro, mientras que en el segundo caso te faltaría agregar más detalles sobre cómo están tus datos en la base de datos. En cualquiera de los dos casos, y no relacionado con la pregunta directamente, **el código que compartes es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL**, deberías solucionar ese problema de seguridad cuanto antes.

Comment: intenta asi: `<select multiple="multiple" size="5" name="tipo[]"  onChange="getPersonal(this.value) ;"     >';` recuerda que estas pasando como array y debes configurar el método de insertar.

Answer (score 1):

Debes insertar mediante el `insert into`:

Primer código:

```
<HTML>
  <BODY class="con">
    <!-- CONTENIDO DE LA PAGINA -->
    <h2>Formulario de inscripción:</h2>
    <br><hr>
    <div class="account-box">
      <form name="registro" id="registro" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
        <!-- lo pego aqui? yes -->
        <?php if(isset($smsg)){ ?><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> <?php echo $smsg; ?> </div><?php }?>
        <?php if(isset($fmsg)){ ?><div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> <?php echo $fmsg; ?> </div><?php }?>

        <span>Nombres: </span>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" value="" placeholder="Digita tus nombres"><br><br><br>
        <span>Apellidos: </span>
        <input type="text" name="apellido" value="" placeholder="Digita tus apellidos"><br><br><br>
        <span>Teléfono: </span>
        <input type="text" name="telefono" value="" placeholder="Digita tu teléfono"><br><br><br>
        <span>Dirección: </span>
        <input type="text" name="direcccion" value="" placeholder="Digita tu direccción"><br><br><br>
        <span>Correo electrónico: </span>
        <input type="text" name="correo" value="" placeholder="Digita tu correo"><br><br><br>
        <button type="submit" name="boton">Registrarse</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</HTML>
```

Segundo código:

```
</HEAD>
  <?php require('connect.php');
  //If the values are posted, insert them into the database.
  //if (
  //  isset($_POST['nombre'])
  //  && isset($_POST['apellido'])
  //  && isset($_POST['telefono'])
  //  && isset($_POST['direccion'])
  // && isset($_POST['correo'])){

  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $smsg = "POST enviado.";
    if( isset($_POST['boton']) ) {
      echo "pasó por aquí ";
      // console.log("¿Entró al if?");
      $_nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
      $_apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
      $_telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
      $_direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
      $_correo = $_POST['correo'];

      $query = "INSERT INTO `usuarios` (nombre,apellido,telefono,direccion,correo) VALUES ('$_nombre', '$_apellido', '$_telefono', '$_direccion', '$_correo' )";
      $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

      //print("Conexion+$connection");
      //print("Consulta+$query");

      if($result){
        $smsg = "Usuario creado correctamente.";
      }else{
        $fmsg = "Usuario no registrado";
      }
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

la solución que propongo para este problema es:

En el html:

```
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
    <select name="selector[]" size="5" multiple="multiple"> <!-- crea un arreglo para ser enviado por metodo de post o de get -->
            <option value="1">uno</option>
            <option value="1">dos</option>
            <option value="1">tres</option>
          </select>
</form>
```

En el script PHP:

```
    <?php
        require ('../php/conexion2.php');

        $opciones = "";
        $esPrimero = 0;
        foreach ($_GET['selector'] as $opcionesSeleccionadas){
          echo $opcionesSeleccionadas."\n";
           if ($esPrimero == 0){
            $opciones =  $opciones . $opcionesSeleccionadas;
            $esPrimero = 1;
           }
           else{
            $opciones =  $opciones . ", " . $opcionesSeleccionadas;
           }

        }
    $query = "SELECT id_tipo, nombre FROM tipo_emergencia WHERE id_clasificacion IN('$opciones') ORDER BY nombre";

  // ETC ETC 
?>
```